# how to automatically compile class files after push to git

Tags: git, deployment, compilation, hook, git-post-receive

I want to be automatically compiled class files after push a git server.
Is there a possible way?
Static files are synchronized to checkout that was using hooks post-receive, I would like to also sync class files.

Ultimately, I would like to automatically deploy web source that pushed to git server.

ps : I tried using ant on post-receive as below for this, but failed

#### post-receive ################

#!/bin/sh

git checkout -f

cd /d/webapps

ant

###############################

Comment: Typically you would set up a continuous integration server such as Jenkins to do this.

Comment: because update only changed source, not use CI service

Comment: @SubyLee That makes no sense. Jenkins can be configured to automatically build your code whenever the source changes. Try it out.